# Is this method of instantiation follows design patterns and clean code?

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, structure, game-development

I'm writing a small game and I use Kotlin for that. I want to model my buildings with the following class:

```java
class Building (
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {}
```

I want to create multiple instances of this class for the map but I don't want to fill the constructor parameters every time with the same data for the same building. So my idea was to make the constructor private and write creator functions in the compainon object.

```java
class Building private constructor(
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {

    companion object {
        fun createWoodcutter(): Building = Building(
            "Woodcutter",
            arrayOf(
                Resource(ResourceType.WOOD, 1),
                Resource(ResourceType.WORKFORCE, 3),
                Resource(ResourceType.MONEY, 10)
            ),
            arrayOf(Resource(ResourceType.PLANKS, 1))
        )
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this strategy counts as clean code or is there a better way or design pattern for this?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

**Other option**: use a special method (similar to a Simple Factory pattern) like:

```
enum class TypeBuilding { WOOD, CONCRETE, METAL }
...
fun createBuilding(type: TypeBuilding) = when (type) {
    TypeBuilding.WOOD -> Building("Woodcutter", ...)
    TypeBuilding.CONCRETE -> Building("Concrete", ...) 
    TypeBuilding.METAL -> Building("Metal", ...)
}
...
val building1 = createBuilding(TypeBuilding.WOOD)
val building2 = createBuilding(TypeBuilding.CONCRETE)
val building3 = createBuilding(TypeBuilding.METAL)
val building4 = createBuilding(TypeBuilding.WOOD)
...
```

In my opinion, your variant is well suited for creating objects with a fixed set of types, and is clean code because it does not affect the logic of the Building class. You can also make an public constructor to create an arbitrary object when necessary:

```
class Building(
    val name: String,
    val inputs: Array<Resource>,
    val outputs: Array<Resource>
) {
    companion object {
        fun createWoodcutter(): Building = ... 
    }
}
```